# Is there a way to remove duplicate where statements in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in Haskell:

```
move :: Camera -> (Double, Double, Double) -> Camera
move camera (xt, yt, zt) = camera { cPosition = (x + xt, y + yt, z + zt) }
    where (x, y, z) = cPosition camera

moveForward :: Camera -> Camera
moveForward camera = move camera (-1 * sin ya, 0, -1 * cos ya)
    where (_, ya, _) = cRotation camera

moveBackward :: Camera -> Camera
moveBackward camera = move camera (sin ya, 0, cos ya)
    where (_, ya, _) = cRotation camera
```

You'll notice that the `moveForward` and `moveBackward` functions have identical `where` statements. Is there a way to remove this duplication? I have numerous functions with the same `where` clauses (read: more than two).

I would prefer not to pass it in as another argument - since it will never change. It will always be `cRotation`.

Comment: Have you considered switching from the awkward `(Double, Double, Double)` to something dedicated, like [`Data.Vect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vect-0.4.7/docs/Data-Vect-Double-Base.html#t:Vec3)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have - I'm waiting on two things, however. The first is that, because the topic is new to me, everything changes daily. The second is I am not sure where I will have to optimize specific things. After things become more concrete, I will take a look at `Data.Vect`, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about making these functions take the tuple as an argument, and then wrapping them with another function that automatically does the boring work of extracting the tuple?

```
rotated :: ((Double, Double, Double) -> Camera -> a) -> Camera -> a
rotated f camera = f (cPosition camera) camera

moveForward :: Camera -> Camera
moveForward = rotated moveForward'
    where moveForward' (_, ya, _) camera = move camera (-1 * sin ya, 0, -1 * cos ya)

moveBackward :: Camera -> Camera
moveBackward = rotated moveBackward'
    where moveBackward' (_, ya, _) camera = move camera (sin ya, 0, cos ya)
```

**Edit**: Reviewing my answer six months later, I note there is some more duplication that could be lifted out: the `move camera` call. So really your functions like `moveForward` can just take a 3-tuple and return a 3-tuple, like so:

```
moveRotated :: ((Double, Double, Double) -> (Double, Double, Double)) -> Camera -> Camera
moveRotated f camera = move camera . f $ cPosition camera

moveForward :: Camera -> Camera
moveForward = moveRotated forward
    where forward (_, ya, _) = (- sin ya, 0, - cos ya)

moveBackward :: Camera -> Camera
moveBackward = moveRotated backward
    where backward (_, ya, _) = (sin ya, 0, cos ya)
```

This gives less power to `moveForward` and `moveBackward`, of course, since you can't use them to do anything but move. But it nicely distills them down to their essences, and ensures you can't accidentally do something other than move.

Comment: I think I will use this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's the simple answer of just define your own function

```
snd3 :: (a, b, c) -> b
snd3 (a, b, c) = b
```

And then you could use a lambda

```
moveForward camera = \ya -> (-1 * sin ya, 0, -1 * cos ya) $ snd3 $ cRotation camera

moveBackward camera = \ya -> (sin ya, 0, cos ya) $ snd3 $ cRotation camera
```

Or if you want to add the `lens` library as a dependency, you can replace `snd3 cRotation camera` with `cRotation camera ^. _2` or equivalently `view _2 $ cRotation camera`.  As for removing that lambda, there isn't much you can do other than defining a new function

```
apply3 :: (a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> (c -> c') -> (a, b, c) -> (a', b', c')
apply3 f1 f2 f3 (a, b, c) = (f1 a, f2 b, f3 c)

moveForward = apply3 (negate . sin) (const 0) (negate . cos) . snd3 . cRotation

moveBackward = apply3 sin (const 0) cos . snd3 . cRotation
```

And use some eta-reduction.

Unfortunately, there are lots of elegant tricks for working with 2-tuples but not as many for 3-tuples.

Comment: In my opinion, that is less readable at a first glance. (This might be because I'm still not advanced in Haskell, though.) EDIT: Although I did ask for removal of duplication, I am weighing it against readability.

Comment: @sdasdadas I wouldn't say that the `apply3` is particularly readable either.  amalloy's solution is pretty clean, I think it's probably the better of the two.